# Multiple versions of Python installed in different locations - How do I set Python 3.10 as my current version?

Tags: python, python-requests, homebrew, python-3.9, python-3.10

I am brand new to programming and installed Python 3.10 from the website (not via terminal). When I began to run code, my computer ran python 2.7 by default. In order to fix this, I installed Python with Brew which updated my default Python version to 3.9.13. However, when I now install libraries like Requests (pip3 install requests), they are installed in the Python 3.10 version I originally downloaded.

Here's where my libraries go:

```
requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

My current version:

```
python --version Python 3.9.13
```

I am not sure if it is best to set default version to 3.10 or to some how install libraries in 3.9.13.

Please advise.

Comment: you'll want to uninstall the python 3.10 you installed outside of brew. I would just uninstall all pythons, then do ```brew install --cask miniconda``` and use conda as your environment mananger. then you can create envronments set to specific versions. ```conda create -n python3_10_env python=3.10``` ```conda create -n p3_9_env python=3.9``` ```conda activate python3_10_env``` ```conda activate p3_9_env```

Comment: better keep `python 2.7` as default version because system can need it ro run some elements. And use command `python3.9` to run your code- and `pip3.9 install ...` or `python3.9 -m pip install ...`. Version `3.10` is very fresh version and some modules may be not ready for this version so better wait few months and use `3.9`